# set zoom to show all the pins in screen / Android studio

Tags: java, android, location

I want to set custom zoom for showing all of pins in screen.
this is my code. now i just showing the last one of latlng from my list.
im junior in android developing and im little confused now :)
would anyone help me?
any idea??

```
    private void getAllPins() {

    for (int i = 0; i < App.listReporter.size(); i++) {

        Reporter object = App.listReporter.get(i);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(object.getfLat(), object.getfLon());
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(activity, R.drawable.marker1)));
        marker.setTag(i);

    }

    Reporter reporter = App.listReporter.get(0);
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(reporter.getfLat(), reporter.getfLon());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( ll, 16));

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_custom_marker_title1, null, false);
            view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(700, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            Reporter object = App.listReporter.get((int) marker.getTag());

            TextView tv_date = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            tv_date.setText(object.getStrDate());


            TextView tv_sTime = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sTime);
            tv_sTime.setText(object.getStrParkTime());

            TextView tv_eTime = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_eTime);
            tv_eTime.setText(object.getStrETime());

            TextView tv_time = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            tv_time.setText(object.getStrSTime());

            TextView tv_address = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
            tv_address.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.strAddress) + "   " + object.getStrAddress());

            return view;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i could solve this problem and i wrote the solution here for anyone who seek for the answer:\

```
 int padding = 200;
 List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();


    if (markers.size() > 1){
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu);
    } else {
        CameraUpdate one = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markers.get(0).getPosition(), 15);

        mMap.animateCamera(one);
    }
```

I hope it could save your time!